# Call PHP function with parameter onSubmit / onClick event

Tags: php, ajax, function, button, call

I have a PHP file containing a `shop` class, which has several static public functions like:

- `createBasket()`
- `getProductNameFromId()`
- ...

File : shop.php

And one of my function is :

```
static public function insertProductIntoBasket($id, $quantity, $name)

{ 
$basket = self::createBasket(); // We create the basket in another function if not exist before handling a product for a basket.

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable(id_order, id_product, quantity_product, file_name)
VALUES('".$basket['id_order']."', '".$id."', '".$quantity."', '".$name."')

;") or die($query.' '.mysql_error());

}
```

In another file (product file) I want to make a button, to handle this function, thank to an event on it.

So I am trying to call this PHP function `insertProductIntoBasket($id, $quantity, $name)` like this, with an event on a button:

File: product.php

```
<form name="addProduct" method="post" action="shop.php">
   <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" name="pdt_basket"/>
</form>
```

I saw that Javascript is handled when the button is pressed, and there is a way to call a function with AJAX. But I definetly do not know how to pass parameters from my `insertProductIntoBasket` function.

Comment: Look at the `$_POST['pdt_basket']` in shop.php. You cannot directly call the function, but you can check the value of `$_POST['pdt_basket']` and execute the function if it is set. If you want to add additional data to your form, try making a custom ajax call (jQuery is the easiest)

Comment: You can't call PHP function from JavaScript. What you can do is an AJAX call to PHP backend and then call whatever PHP code you want passing parameters you get with GET or POST superglobals. If you want to do it properly, look at Symfony's HttpFoundation component which enables you to create nice Request object you can pass to your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to call product.php

`function blah()
{
$.ajax({ url: 'product.php?arg1=val1&arg2=val2&arg3=val3' });
}`

and use $1 $2 etc to access passed values

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function from with your shop.php file. You can get the post variables and call the appropriate functions from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Before you use ajax, you have to know how to pass(POST) parameter first,
//The following is a simple example

/*In product.php
* if you want to send parameter from this page,
* just create more input field within the form
* then the form will "POST" those parameter to shop.php
*/

<form name="addProduct" method="post" action="shop.php">
   <input name="id_order" type="text" value="1" />
   <input name="id_product" type="text" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" name="pdt_basket"/>
</form>

/*In : shop.php
*you can get those parameter by using $_POST['input_name']
*the following is the example to get the id_order and id_product send from product.php
*/

$id_order = $_POST['id_order'];
$id_product = $_POST['id_product'];

/* Then you can try to call function inside shop.php will calling function directly */
insertProductIntoBasket($para);

//You may not need AJAX in this case, I will update my answer if you require for it.
```

Comment: Thank you L.C. Echo Chan.

So now I use my form like this :

`<form name="addProduit" method="post" action="shop.php">

>   <input hidden="true" type="text" name="pdt_id" value="3"/>
>   <label>Quantité du produit </label><input type="text" name="pdt_qtte" value="2"/>
>   <input hidden="true" type="text" name="pdt_name" value="Test"/>
>   <input type="submit" value="Ajouter au panier" name="pdt_panier"/>
>   </form>`

But where have I to write it :

`shop::insertProduitIntoPanier($_POST['pdt_id'], $_POST['pdt_qtte'], $_POST['pdt_name']);`

From my shop.php which contains my function ?

Comment: Just write it on any place that can have function call..
If u can't get what i am saying, try to write it on the most bottom part in shop.php